# Grails on Google App Engine - Production Issue: Response 500 Error

Tags: google-app-engine, grails

I am using Grails (app-engine and gorm-jpa plugins) for the development.

I don't know why, But my application is running fine on local environment. But on Google App Engine, I am in-consistently (1 in 3 times) getting Error Code-500.

Also, in GAE logs - reason of request failure is its taking so long to execute the request (usually more than 30 seconds).

Have anyone worked around the same kind of problem?

-Salil.Kalia

Answer (score 0):

Have faced the same problem. Apparently grails startup and initialization take sufficiently long to exceed the deadline limit enforced by the app engine. See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS-1736

It was frustrating enough to have me migrate my app to Gaelyk - tough luck cause i really like grails